# Detect changes in html using Django?

Tags: python, html, django

First of all, I'm very very new to web development (a few days), so I might say something that doesn't make sense.

I am writing a music web app using Django and I want to display a piano keyboard, have the user play some keys and then be able to retrieve this data (the notes the user played). I was able to embed the piano thanks to [this](https://mczak.com/code/piano/), but I don't know how to get the data back. I tried wrapping the html key tags (`<li class="key">...</li>`) within a form tag and a submit bottom but I can't get it to work properly, and I'm not even sure if it's possible this way.

Then I realized, when you press some key, the tag's class changes from `class="key"` to `class="key.active"`, so I was wondering if there is a way to detect these changes in the `.html` and thus be able to store the data. Does this even make sense? Maybe write a `.py` script to read the `.html` as a string and look for this changes? But does the `.html` file stored in the server change, or does it only change on the user's browser? I haven't found any info on the matter, which makes me think it might not be possible...

Comment: Where/how do you want to store the changes? In a Django model?

Comment: Not really, I just need use them to create a new view and then I don't need them anymore.